# Translating objective C code to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have to translate some objective-C code to Swift and I'm pretty new in Swift and a complete Noob in objective-C.

It's this line which makes trouble:

```
MyStreamingVideoView* view = (MyStreamingVideoView*)self.view;
```

I've translated it with:

```
let view = self.view as! MyStreamingVideoView
```

But I'm getting this error on in:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x19f802608) to 'MyStreamingVideoView' (0x1001ba938)
```

Well the code I've to translate is a little more so I paste the whole code and show you how I translated it:

Objective C:

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/if.h>

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RTPReceiver.h"
#import "MyStreamingVideoView.h"

#define LISTEN_PORT 5000

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong) RTPReceiver* receiver;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSString* ip = [self findLocalWifiIp];
    NSLog(@"local IP: %@",ip);

    MyStreamingVideoView* view = (MyStreamingVideoView*)self.view;
    view.waiting = YES;

    self.receiver = [[RTPReceiver alloc] initWithLocalIp:ip listenPort:LISTEN_PORT];
    self.receiver.delegate = view;
    [view setNeedsDisplay];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(decodingFailed:)
                                                 name:AVSampleBufferDisplayLayerFailedToDecodeNotification
                                               object:self.view.layer];


}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.receiver = nil;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}

- (void) decodingFailed:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"decoding failed: %@",notification.userInfo[AVSampleBufferDisplayLayerFailedToDecodeNotificationErrorKey]);
}


@end
```

Swift Code:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    //ERROR WITH THIS LINE
    self.receiver = nil

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let ip = RTPTools().findLocalWifiIp()
    print("local IP: \(ip)")

    //ERROR WITH THIS LINE
    let view = self.view as! MyStreamingVideoView
    view.waiting = true

    self.receiver = RTPReceiver(localIp: ip, listenPort: 5000)
    self.receiver.delegate = view
    view.setNeedsDisplay()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MasterViewController.decodingFailed(_:)), name: AVSampleBufferDisplayLayerFailedToDecodeNotification, object: self.view.layer)

}

func decodingFailed(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("decoding failed: ")
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess that in storyboard/xib the author changed the class of `self.view` to `MyStreamingVideoView`, or changed the IBOutlet (if there is a IBOutlet).

Comment: Ah you are right in the storyboard the view is from class MyStremVideoView. Thanks. And whats the problem with self.receiver = nil ?

Comment: What's the error message? I don't speak Swift, but it may be related to how you declared `self.receiver`, with a "?" or a "!" maybe.

Comment: Error message: Nil cannot be assigned to type 'RTPReceiver'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863119/nil-cannot-be-assigned-to-type-avcapturedeviceinput ?

Comment: Ah now I see the problem more clear